# Is it possible to add some defined lines of code to webpack's bundle in the dist folder

Tags: webpack

I want to import my output file in the `dist` folder into another project.
So I want to add these lines (first and last line) to the resulting bundle:

```
export function main() {
  (... here normal webpack bundle)
}
```

Is it possible to program this with webpack? (probably, but where should I look?)

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, you can.

> With Webpack `compiler` and `compilation` hooks you can manage Webpack output.
> Webpack provides several hooks to manage output at different stages of [compiler](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/) and [compilation](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/).

You can update assets at `processAssets` hook of compilation, where you get optimized assets.

Update `webpack.config.js` with the following snippet.

```
const { Compilation, sources } = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: {},
    module: {},
    plugins: [
        {
            apply(compiler) {
                compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap('Replace', (compilation) => {
                    compilation.hooks.processAssets.tap({ name: 'TEST_PLUGIN', stage: Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ADDITIONAL },
                        (assets) => {
                            //find specific file from assets or iterate through to update each asset    
                            let filelist = Object.entries(assets);

                            //give specific file name
                            const fileContent = compilation.getAsset('app.js');
                            const newFileContent = fileContent.source.source() + '/*additional content to insert*/'
                            compilation.updateAsset('app.js', new sources.RawSource(newFileContent));
                        }
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    ],
};
```

[image]

##### With multiple modules.

You get the list of module details in `processAssets` callback parameter `assets`.

```
{
  'app1.bundle.js': CachedSource {
    _source: ConcatSource { _children: [Array], _isOptimized: false },
    _cachedSourceType: undefined,
    _cachedSource: undefined,
    _cachedBuffer: undefined,
    _cachedSize: undefined,
    _cachedMaps: Map(0) {},
    _cachedHashUpdate: undefined
  },
  'app2.bundle.js': CachedSource {
    _source: ConcatSource { _children: [Array], _isOptimized: false },
    _cachedSourceType: undefined,
    _cachedSource: undefined,
    _cachedBuffer: undefined,
    _cachedSize: undefined,
    _cachedMaps: Map(0) {},
    _cachedHashUpdate: undefined
  }
}
```

The object can be iterated for each build asset.