# Webpack, insert output in already existing file

Tags: javascript, webpack, output, bundle

I am new to webpack and trying to output in an already existing base file my final bundle.

I have a function main() and want to print there my bundle

[image: 1]

Has anyone ever had my same problem? May yoou help me out? Thanks in advance!

Googling, i found out this question but didn't help out
[Is it possible to add some defined lines of code to webpack's bundle in the dist folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264104/is-it-possible-to-add-some-defined-lines-of-code-to-webpacks-bundle-in-the-dist)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this several different ways. If you're not having any luck with advanced Webpack config options, a little Node script should do the trick:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const bundleContents = fs.readFileSync('./path/to/bundle.js', 'utf8')
const fileToModify = fs.readFileSync('./path/to/file-to-modify.js', 'utf8').split('\n')
const lineToModify = fileToModify.findIndex((l) =>
    l.includes('INSERT HERE WEBPACK OUTPUT'))
fileToModify[lineToModify] = bundleContents
fs.writeFileSync('./path/to-destination-file.js', fileToModify.join('\n'))
```

Note that this *really* is not robust, with hardcoded paths and lines to look for, though it is probably safer than using a shell script with sed et al. A better option might be to use a codemod or some other tool that understands ASTs, or to keep trying with compiler hooks as in the answer you linked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, i don't know sed. I'll try to sort out something!